# how to create a shared view in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget

I am having one app where i created a view. And i want to use the same view in another application. Is there any way to pass the second apps context as parameter to the view. So that the view is created second application's context.

Or is there any way to create a view library so that many applications use that view library to create views.

Ron

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a class and call it `CustomView` wich extends `View` and customize the view. Then, you can use it in both apps.

However, since you already created your view, my suggestion is to copy-paste the code into your new app unless you are planning to use the same view in future apps.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i used this approach to copy the code. A small improvement i can think of is to have a library project of all the required views and reference that library project across the apps required.

Comment: You're welcome. Your improvement is so useful if you have more than one view that are related to each other. This will support of portability of the library and this is how libraries born :)

Answer (score 1):

I see two ways to interpret your question.   1) You have a custom View (like a custom control) and want to share it.  The earlier answers address that interpretation of the question -- how to share the code that implements the View.

Another interpretation is you want Application "A" to bring up a screen defined by Application "B".  That is you want not only the View, but the behavior behind the view.

For this use I would suggest sharing Activities or Fragments rather than Views.  You can have application A use Application B's Activity (if Application B is willing) by sending an appropriate Intent.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you follow iturki's method or just copying the same layout into each application xml layout file..I dont think that is to difficult. It is practically easier.

Answer (score 0):

In Android source build system you can usually create a jar and export that jar to multiple apps to share the common functionality. Never tried doing it independently. You can check Phone app on Gingerbread. Some functionality is shared between Phone app and Contacts app. Though these are not sharing Views, Ideally you could take this idea forward and implement Views